# If else statement to filter out rows using dates and matching values across multiple columns in R

Tags: r, if-statement, filter, dplyr

I'm trying to do a rather complicated filter using `if else` and I keep getting turned around in circles.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
individual_id born        mom_id trap_date 
        13212 2013-03-16  11926  2014-06-26
        13213 2013-03-16  11926  2013-07-23
        13214 2013-03-16  11926  2015-06-01
        13212 2013-03-16  11926  2014-06-26
        11926 2010-04-08  10422  2013-01-23
        11926 2010-04-08  10422  2013-02-01
        11926 2010-04-08  10422  2013-03-08
        11926 2010-04-08  10422  2013-03-12
        11926 2010-04-08  10422  2013-04-23
        11926 2010-04-08  10422  2013-05-01
        11926 2010-04-08  10422  2013-08-23
        11926 2010-04-08  10422  2013-09-01
        11926 2010-04-08  10422  2013-10-23
        11926 2010-04-08  10422  2013-12-01
```

I have a column called `mom_id` and these individuals also show up in the `individual_id` column.

I'd like to remove any `trap_date` records that occur - 35 days or + 70 days from the `born` date for a `mom_id`, *only if* she also shows up in the `individual_id` column.

So, in this example, I'd like to remove all `trap_date` records/rows that are between February 9, 2013 (`2013-02-09`) and May 25, 2013 (`2013-05-25`) because the `born` date for `mom_id` 11926 is March 16, 2013 (`2013-03-16`).

Desired result:

```
individual_id born        mom_id trap_date 
        13212 2013-03-16  11926  2014-06-26
        13213 2013-03-16  11926  2013-07-23
        13214 2013-03-16  11926  2015-06-01
        13212 2013-03-16  11926  2014-06-26
        11926 2010-04-08  10422  2013-01-23
        11926 2010-04-08  10422  2013-02-01
        11926 2010-04-08  10422  2013-08-23
        11926 2010-04-08  10422  2013-09-01
        11926 2010-04-08  10422  2013-10-23
        11926 2010-04-08  10422  2013-12-01
```

A `dplyr` solution would be appreciated, but I'd appreciate any help at this point!

Comment: Perhaps, I am misled but I believe born date for `mom_id` 11926 is 2010-04-08 not 2013-03-16 which is the born date for `mom_id` 19262, isn't it? The ids look confusingly similar.

Comment: That's a fair question! Because individuals show up in both the `mom_id` and `individual_id` column, it is confusing to figure out what `born` corresponds to. But, `born` is the date `mom_id` has to be filtered from (so `mom_id==11926` has a `born` date of `2013-03-16` and `mom_id==10422` has a `born` date of `2010-04-08`).

Comment: Thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this can be solved using a *non-equi anti-join*:

```
library(data.table)
df2 <- unique(setDT(df1)[, .(mom_id, lo = born - 35, hi = born + 70)])
df1[!df1[df2, on = c("individual_id == mom_id", "trap_date >= lo", "trap_date <= hi"),
    nomatch = NULL, which = TRUE]]
```

> ```
>     individual_id       born mom_id  trap_date
>  1:         19262 2013-03-16  11926 2014-06-26
>  2:         19263 2013-03-16  11926 2013-07-23
>  3:         19264 2013-03-16  11926 2015-06-01
>  4:         19262 2013-03-16  11926 2014-06-26
>  5:         11926 2010-04-08  10422 2013-01-23
>  6:         11926 2010-04-08  10422 2013-02-01
>  7:         11926 2010-04-08  10422 2013-08-23
>  8:         11926 2010-04-08  10422 2013-09-01
>  9:         11926 2010-04-08  10422 2013-10-23
> 10:         11926 2010-04-08  10422 2013-12-01
> ```

#### Explanation

- For each unique `mom_id` the range `lo` to `hi`of dates to be removed is computed. So, `df2` becomes

  > ```
  >    mom_id         lo         hi
  > 1:  11926 2013-02-09 2013-05-25
  > 2:  10422 2010-03-04 2010-06-17
  > ```
- Now, the row numbers of the rows to be removed are identified by a *non-equi join*

  ```
   df1[df2, on = c("individual_id == mom_id", "trap_date >= lo", "trap_date <= hi"),
       nomatch = NULL, which = TRUE]
  ```

  which returns

  > [1]  7  8  9 10
- Finally, these rows are removed from `df1` by subsetting (using `!`)

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- fread("individual_id born        mom_id trap_date 
        19262 2013-03-16  11926  2014-06-26
        19263 2013-03-16  11926  2013-07-23
        19264 2013-03-16  11926  2015-06-01
        19262 2013-03-16  11926  2014-06-26
        11926 2010-04-08  10422  2013-01-23
        11926 2010-04-08  10422  2013-02-01
        11926 2010-04-08  10422  2013-03-08
        11926 2010-04-08  10422  2013-03-12
        11926 2010-04-08  10422  2013-04-23
        11926 2010-04-08  10422  2013-05-01
        11926 2010-04-08  10422  2013-08-23
        11926 2010-04-08  10422  2013-09-01
        11926 2010-04-08  10422  2013-10-23
        11926 2010-04-08  10422  2013-12-01")
```

Comment: Are there any other packages I should have installed? R is telling me it could not find function "."

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist, I was able to reproduce the issue. It can be fixed by coercing `df1` to class `data.table`. See my update. I am sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you're looking for.

```
mutate(df, in_individual = mom_id %in% individual_id) %>%
    filter((!in_individual) | ((born - 35 <= trap_date) & (trap_date <= born + 70)))
```

Comment: Is there a typo in your solution? I get this error: `Error: unexpected '<=' in:
"        in_individual = mom_id %in% individual_id) %>% filter((!in_id) || born - 35 <= trap_date <="`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot R doesn't support chaining comparison operators. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First we convert both `born` and `trap_date` to dates, in case they're only text. Then we check the `mom_id`. Finally, we check the `trap_date`.

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    across(c(born, trap_date), lubridate::ymd), # applies ymd parser over both columns
    in_individual = mom_id %in% individual_id,
    within_interval = 
      trap_date %within% 
        interval(
          start = born - 35,
          end = .born + 70)) %>%
    filter(in_individual, within_interval) # filter out conditional on both
```

## Edit

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    across(c(born, trap_date), lubridate::ymd), # applies ymd parser over both columns
    in_individual = mom_id %in% individual_id,
    within_interval = purrr::map2_lgl(
      .x = trap_date,
      .y = born,
      .f = ~ .x %within%
        interval(
          start = .y - 35,
          end = .y + 70)) %>%
    filter(in_individual, within_interval) # filter out conditional on both
```

Comment: I get an error for this the within-interval part of your solution: `Error: Problem with mutate() input within_interval`.

Comment: I've editted my answer. Mapping over both inputs should work just fine.